# Third party tools in Visual Studio Team Services Continuous Integration

Tags: continuous-integration, obfuscation, azure-devops

I am planning to move from TeamCity to Visual Studio Team Services CI builds (mainly to avoid having to run and manager a server for TeamCity, version control repository etc.)

My TeamCity build uses a third party obfuscator, called Crypto Obfuscator for obfuscating code when it is built. I have searched through all available documentation online but cannot find out if Team Services lets you somehow install and use third party tools in CI builds.

If not, is there any way obfuscation can be introduced in Team Services CI builds?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new build system is task-based -- you can either write a custom task and upload it to Team Services, or just call the appropriate command-line utilities on your build server.

If you're using a hosted build server, you'll have no ability to install third-party tools.

Comment: Thanks for the information Daniel. Any idea if Dotfuscator can be somehow pushed to TFS hosted build server? I am willing to switch to Dotfuscator if its possible., assuming it comes installed on hosted build server for Azure VSO

Comment: VSO builds are not ready fr my needs. Decided to stick with TeamCity.

Answer (score 0):

The Team Services build service (build server hosted by Microsoft) is not for you. You won't be able to run the obfuscation program you have.
But you can use your own Build server, connect it to Team Services and keep your MSBuild script.

Comment: Thanks Fabien. I did exactly what you suggest here. Running TeamCity builds that pull code from VSO.

Comment: Great! I love VSOnline for that